# Unable to find text from the html content beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
text = "<tr>
<td style="width:127.5pt;padding:3.75pt 0in 3.75pt 0in" width="170">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">Job #<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:3.75pt 0in 3.75pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><strong><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif'>TEST-12311</span></strong><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
print(soup)
job_number = soup.find("span", string="Job #")
print(job_number)
```

When I search for `Job #` it is showing `None`. But there is a `<span>` with text `Job #`.

Is there any solution to find `<span>` text which is followed by `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to check Job # is there or not in the html content

You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with pseudo class, to check if element contains a string:

```
soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Job #")')
```

or to check if it also has a sibling `<td>`:

```
soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Job #"):has(+ td)')
```

---

The other way around the combination that selects the sibling `<td>` of a `<td>` that contains a `<span>` with your string:

```
soup.select_one('td:has(span:-soup-contains("Job #")) + td').get_text(strip=True)
```

or not that strict:

```
soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Job #") + td').get_text(strip=True)
```

both above will give you `TEST-12311` just in case that your string was found in previous sibling `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
soup.find_all('span')[1].text
```

It gives you:

```
TEST-12311
```

Comment: I have to check Job # is there or not in the html content. Actually it is present as span text but it is showing None because another tag <o:p> is present. How to find it